# Modify user signup behaviour in meteor accounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am following the ["To-do list" tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/adding-user-accounts) for meteor and trying to make a few changes to it. I am trying to add a few fields by default to a collection called records(same as the collection tasks until now) when she signs up.

I came across [this](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser) and wrote the following piece of code in startup/accounts-config.js

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import { Rec } from '../api/records.js';

Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_ONLY',
});

Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    Rec.insert({
      "text",
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: this.userId,
      username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
    });

    return user;
});
```

But my application wouldn't compile and throw this error

```
imports/startup/accounts-config.js:12:12: Unexpected token (12:12)
```

Could someone please help me with this? I am new to front end development.

Answer (score 0):

"text" is sitting on it's own without a value, you probably mean this:

text: "something goes here...",

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you have `this.userId`. You should use `user._id` there which is the created user object and `user.username` for the username.

```
Rec.insert({
  "text",
  createdAt: new Date(),
  owner: user._id,
  username: user.username,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mikkel said,
There should always be a field and value pair in a query , 
You are passing only value here , This should be like

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
Rec.insert({
  field:"text",
  createdAt: new Date(),
  owner: this.userId,
  username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
});
```